# Windows Store App: Change language programmatically

Tags: localization, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App where the user should be able to change its language.
One Screen 1 he selects his language. Then the app switches to screen 2 in the correct language.

My problem is, that screen 2 doesn't get initiated with the correct language. If I switch back to screen 1 and change to a different language, screen 2 has the language selected before.

My localization is located in Resources.resw files.

Here is the code I use:

```
 private void ChangeLanguage(SupportedLanguage language)
    {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfoForSupportedLanguage(language);

            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cultureInfo.Name;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo; 

            ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();

         Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
         rootFrame.Language = cultureInfo.Name;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows Store Apps.
I fixed this with a little workaround:

switched - like you - with

```
 Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
```

But I also deleted the Navigation Cache

```
  var Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        Frame.CacheSize = 0;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Screen1));
        Frame.CacheSize = *your Cachesize*;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Screen2));
        Frame.GoBack();
```

It worked in my case, hope something similar is going to help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works on the first language change, but on the second change the app crashes and the debugger can't handle it.

Comment: @netshark1000 i am having the same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember. It was very complicated. I stopped developing for windows. The horse is dead.